# Loop over files zsh

Tags: shell, zsh

I've been searching but I haven't found anything that work for me.
I'm quite new to shell scripting and zsh and I'm trying to loop over a bunch of files in one directory.

So let's say that I've got 5000 files in a very specific format `.su` that can only be handled by a specific software. I need to sum those files with a subprogram called `suop2` that sum them by pairs.
I'm looking for a clever way to sum all the files and merge them into just one single file. Take into account that I can just sum 2 files at a time with `suop2`. The files look like,

```
*tt.su
```

I've been thinking in using a `for` loop but I'm not sure how to handle the intermediate files created after summing 2 of them.

Anyone has a good idea on how to do it? Any advice will be very appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: How is `suop2` run? Does it take named files as arguments, or can it read from standard input? Does it write to a named file, or can it write to standard output? Is there an "identity" for `suop2`, a file which when added to any file `x` produces `x`, or do you have to have at least two input files?

Comment: @chepner `Suop2` works with 2 named files in `.su` format and writes to a named file, `Suop2 file1 file2 op=sum > file3`. To run the command you need two files. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you have a program that “adds” two files to produce a “sum”, and you want to sum all of the files. So keep a working total, and add one file at a time to that total.

The first file is the original total. Then add files to it, one at a time.

I use two temporary files: one that contains the partial sum, and one that contains the next sum. This may not be necessary if `suop2` is able to merge into an existing file. The reason for using a temporary file for the partial sums is so that the final result file (`total.su`) isn't created with a partial sum, that way if this file exists you know that it's a valid sum that represents all the files at some point in time.

```
#!/bin/zsh
# Exit on any error
set -e
# Clean up temporary files on error
trap 'rm -f partial_sum.su next_sum.su' EXIT INT TERM
# Collect the files
files=(*tt.su(N))
if ((!#files)); then
  echo 'No files to add!'
  exit 2
fi
# Set up the initial partial sum
cp files[0] partial_sum.su
shift files
# Process all the other files
for input in $files; do
  suop2 $input partial_sum.su >next_sum.su
  mv next_sum.su partial_sum.su
done
# We have a result
mv partial_sum.su total.su
```

Answer (score -1):

You only need one intermediate file, to accumulate the result. I'll assume that `suop2` is run like this

```
suop2 file1 file2 > answer
```

but you can adapt the answer for other use cases.

```
files=( *tt.su )
# Assume at least 2 files
suop2 "${files[@]:0:2}" > answer
for f in "${files[@]:2}"; do
    suop2 "$answer" "$f" > tmp && mv tmp answer
done
```

It's even simpler if `suop2` accepts an identify, say an empty file, which when added to another file just returns that file.

```
touch answer
for f in *tt.su; do
    suop2 answer $f > tmp && mv tmp answer
done
```

Comment: Your scripts don't work because they truncate `answer` due to the redirection before `suop2` even starts.

Comment: That may or may not work depending on how `suop2` works. For example, if it starts generating output before it's finished reading its input, it might get caught in an infinite loop of reading its own output.